# Can not upload Image, Video Entry in Nougat version in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I tried to upload Images / Videos from Android Studio and This working fine in all other Android version but facing issue with nougat.

Anyone can help me to short out this.

package com.ethosapp.ethos.jobs;

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferListener;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferObserver;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferState;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList;
import com.birbit.android.jobqueue.Job;
import com.birbit.android.jobqueue.Params;
import com.birbit.android.jobqueue.RetryConstraint;
import com.ethosapp.ethos.EthosApplication;
import com.ethosapp.ethos.R;
import com.ethosapp.ethos.models.Entry;
import com.ethosapp.ethos.models.PostEntry;
import com.ethosapp.ethos.services.AmazonSyncService;
import com.ethosapp.ethos.services.ApiServiceFactory;
import com.ethosapp.ethos.services.EntryService;

import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import retrofit2.Call;

/**
 * Created by jaya on 25/05/16.
 */
public class UploadFileToS3Job extends Job {

    public static final int PRIORITY = 1;

    protected String filename;
    protected String uri;
    protected String extension;
    protected String fileId;
    protected String entryId;
    protected long type;
    protected String state;

    public UploadFileToS3Job(String filename, String uri, String extension, String fileId, String entryId, long type) {
        super(new Params(PRIORITY).requireNetwork().persist());
        this.filename = filename;
        this.uri = uri;
        this.extension = extension;
        this.fileId = fileId;
        this.type = type;
        this.entryId = entryId;

        try {
            Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(uri);
            File f = new File(fileUri.getPath());
            JSONObject props = new JSONObject();
            props.put("entryId", this.entryId);
            props.put("fileId", this.fileId);
            props.put("extension", this.extension);
            props.put("fileSize", f.length());
            EthosApplication.mixPanelTrack("BeginUploadFile", props);
        } catch (JSONException jsonException) {
            Log.e("MYAPP", "Unable to add properties to JSONObject", jsonException);
        }
    }

    public UploadFileToS3Job(String filename) {
        super(new Params(PRIORITY).requireNetwork().persist());
        Log.e("tag", "fileNAAM" + filename);
        this.filename = filename;
    }




    @Override
    public void onAdded() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRun() throws Throwable {
        switch ((int) this.type) {
            case Entry.Type.IMAGE:
                uploadImageFiles();
                break;
            case Entry.Type.AUDIO:
                uploadVideoAudioFiles();
                break;
            case Entry.Type.VIDEO:
                uploadVideoAudioFiles();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancel(int cancelReason) {

    }

    @Override
    protected RetryConstraint shouldReRunOnThrowable(Throwable throwable, int runCount, int maxRunCount) {
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    private File saveFileToTempFolder(Uri uri, String name, String extension) throws Throwable {
        InputStream inputStream = EthosApplication.getInstance().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        File outputDir = EthosApplication.getInstance().getBaseContext().getCacheDir(); // context being the Activity pointer
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile(name, extension, outputDir);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, out);
        inputStream.close();
        out.close();
        return tempFile;
    }

    private void uploadVideoAudioFiles() throws Throwable {

        Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(uri);
        File file = new File(fileUri.getPath());
        Log.e("FFFFFFFFF====","=="+"content://com.ethosapp.ethos.provider/external_files/EthOS/EthOS%20movies/"+filename);

        if (file.exists()) {
            String parent = fileId + "/";
            uploadFileToS3(parent + filename, file, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);

            // Now schedule a media-transcode
            // Update the Entry
            PostEntry postEntry = new PostEntry();
            postEntry.setFileId(fileId);

            EntryService service = ApiServiceFactory.createRetrofitService(EntryService.class, ApiServiceFactory.API_BASE_URL);

            Call<Entry> entryCall = service.scheduleMediaTranscode(this.entryId, postEntry);
            Entry entry = entryCall.execute().body();

            PostEntry postEntry1 = new PostEntry();
            postEntry.setType("0");

            Call<Entry> entryCall1 = service.updateEntry(this.entryId, postEntry1);
            Entry entry1 = entryCall1.execute().body();

            // TODO: Some Validation to verify the entry is uploaded successfully

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction("com.ethosapp.ethos.CUSTOM_INTENT");
            EthosApplication.getInstance().getBaseContext().sendBroadcast(intent);

        } else {
            // TODO : Error Handling
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    private void uploadImageFiles() throws Throwable {
        Log.e("tag", "images" + uri);
        Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(uri);
        Log.e("tag", "<----fileUri---->" + uri);

        String fileNameWithOutExt = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(filename);
        String fileExtension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(filename);
        String parent = fileId + "/";

        // Upload preview image
        // name : name-preview.jpg (230x0)
        // Dimensions: 230 x 0
        // Quality: 70
        String previewImageFilename = fileNameWithOutExt + "-preview" + "." + fileExtension;
        File previewImage = resizeImage(fileUri, 230, 230, previewImageFilename, 70);
        uploadFileToS3(parent + previewImageFilename, previewImage, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
        previewImage.delete();

        // Upload resized image
        // name : name-resized.jpg (230x0)
        // Dimensions: 1024 x 768
        // Quality: 70
        String resizedImageFilename = fileNameWithOutExt + "-resized" + "." + fileExtension;
        File resizedImage = resizeImage(fileUri, 1024, 768, resizedImageFilename, 70);
        uploadFileToS3(parent + resizedImageFilename, resizedImage, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
        resizedImage.delete();


        // Upload resized image
        // name : name-resized.jpg (230x0)
        // Dimensions: 480 x 800
        // Quality: 60
        String resized1XImageFilename = fileNameWithOutExt + "-resized-1x" + "." + fileExtension;
        File resized1XImage = resizeImage(fileUri, 480, 800, resized1XImageFilename, 60);
        uploadFileToS3(parent + resizedImageFilename, resized1XImage, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
        resized1XImage.delete();

        // Upload resized image
        // name : name-resized.jpg (230x0)
        // Dimensions: 1024 x 768
        // Quality: 60
        String resized2XImageFilename = fileNameWithOutExt + "-resized-2x" + "." + fileExtension;
        File resized2XImage = resizeImage(fileUri, 1024, 768, resized2XImageFilename, 60);
        uploadFileToS3(parent + resizedImageFilename, resized2XImage, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
        resized2XImage.delete();

        // Upload thumbnail image
        // name : name-tn.jpg (230x0)
        // Dimensions: 80 x 80
        // Quality: 70
        String thumbnailImageFilename = fileNameWithOutExt + "-tn" + "." + fileExtension;
        File thumbnailImage = resizeImage(fileUri, 80, 80, thumbnailImageFilename, 70);
        uploadFileToS3(parent + thumbnailImageFilename, thumbnailImage, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
        thumbnailImage.delete();

        //File image = saveFileToTempFolder(fileUri, filename, extension);
        File image = new File(fileUri.getPath());
        uploadFileToS3(parent + filename, image, CannedAccessControlList.Private);

        // Update the Entry
        PostEntry postEntry = new PostEntry();
        postEntry.setType("0");

        EntryService service = ApiServiceFactory.createRetrofitService(EntryService.class, ApiServiceFactory.API_BASE_URL);

        Call<Entry> entryCall = service.updateEntry(this.entryId, postEntry);
        Entry entry = entryCall.execute().body();

        int id=1;

        Context baseContext = EthosApplication.getInstance().getBaseContext();

//        // intent triggered, you can add other intent for other actions
//        Intent intent = new Intent(baseContext, ProjectEntriesActivity.class);
//        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(baseContext, 0, intent, 0);

        NotificationManager mNotifyManager =
                (NotificationManager) baseContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(baseContext);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Entry Uploaded")
                .setContentText("Entry has uploaded successfully.")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);

        mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());

        //Log.e("tag","1111");
        // TODO: Some Validation to verify the entry is uploaded successfully
        //Intent intent = new Intent();
        //intent.setAction("com.ethosapp.ethos.CUSTOM_INTENT");
        //EthosApplication.getInstance().getBaseContext().sendBroadcast(intent);

    }


    private void uploadFileToS3(String filename, File file, CannedAccessControlList acl) throws Throwable {

        Log.e("FILE=======","=="+file);
        Log.e("FILE=======","=="+filename);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        {
            String ff="content://com.ethosapp.ethos.provider/external_files/EthOS/EthOS%20Pictures/"+filename;
            Log.e("FFFF==","=="+ff);
        }
        String ff="content://com.ethosapp.ethos.provider/external_files/EthOS/EthOS%20Pictures/"+filename;
        Log.e("FFFF==","=="+ff);

        Log.e("1111","===================");
        AmazonSyncService syncService = new AmazonSyncService(EthosApplication.getInstance().getBaseContext());
        TransferObserver transferObserver = syncService.startUpload(filename, file, acl);
        transferObserverListener(transferObserver);

        // Code to make the thread to wait for upload completion.
        // Entire code will be running in a background thread, so there is no
        // issue in waiting for it to complete.
        while (true) {
            if (TransferState.COMPLETED.equals(transferObserver.getState())
                    || TransferState.FAILED.equals(transferObserver.getState())) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (TransferState.FAILED.equals(transferObserver.getState())) {
            throw new Exception("Upload File to S3 failed.");
        }
    }

    private void transferObserverListener(TransferObserver transferObserver) {
        transferObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                Log.e("statechange", state + "");

                try {
                    Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(uri);
                    File f = new File(fileUri.getPath());
                    JSONObject props = new JSONObject();
                    props.put("entryId", entryId);
                    props.put("fileId", fileId);
                    props.put("extension", extension);
                    props.put("fileSize", f.length());
                    EthosApplication.mixPanelTrack("UploadedFile", props);
                } catch (JSONException jsonException) {
                    Log.e("MYAPP", "Unable to add properties to JSONObject", jsonException);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
                int percentage = (int) (bytesCurrent / bytesTotal * 100);
                Log.e("percentage", percentage + "");

                if(type == Entry.Type.VIDEO){
                    try {
                        Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(uri);
                        File f = new File(fileUri.getPath());
                        JSONObject props = new JSONObject();
                        props.put("entryId", entryId);
                        props.put("fileId", fileId);
                        props.put("extension", extension);
                        props.put("fileSize", f.length());
                        props.put("percentage", percentage);
                        EthosApplication.mixPanelTrack("UploadingFile", props);
                    } catch (JSONException jsonException) {
                        Log.e("MYAPP", "Unable to add properties to JSONObject", jsonException);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                Log.e("error", "error");
            }
        });
    }

    private File resizeImage(Uri fileUri, int width, int height, String resizedFilename, int quality) throws Throwable {
        int inWidth = 0;
        int inHeight = 0;

        InputStream inputStream = EthosApplication.getInstance().getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
        inputStream.close();

        // save width and height
        inWidth = options.outWidth;
        inHeight = options.outHeight;

        inputStream = EthosApplication.getInstance().getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);
        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        // calc rough re-size (this is no exact resize)
        options.inSampleSize = Math.max(inWidth / width, inHeight / height);
        // decode full image
        Bitmap roughBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
        // calc exact destination size
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        RectF inRect = new RectF(0, 0, roughBitmap.getWidth(), roughBitmap.getHeight());
        RectF outRect = new RectF(0, 0, width, height);
        m.setRectToRect(inRect, outRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
        float[] values = new float[9];
        m.getValues(values);

        // resize bitmap
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(roughBitmap, (int) (roughBitmap.getWidth() * values[0]), (int) (roughBitmap.getHeight() * values[4]), true);
        File outputDir = EthosApplication.getInstance().getBaseContext().getCacheDir(); // context being the Activity pointer
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile(resizedFilename, "jpg", outputDir);
        Log.e("outputDir=====","=="+outputDir);
        Log.e("tempFile=====","=="+tempFile);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, out);

        return tempFile;
    }



}



public class    AmazonSyncService {


    // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
    public  static CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider;

    // Create an S3 client
    private AmazonS3 s3;

    private TransferUtility transferUtility;
    private Context context;


    private final String MY_APP_BUCKET = "ethosappcom-production-media";
    private final String MY_APP_BUCKET_PROFILE = "ethosappcom-production-user";

    public AmazonSyncService(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                this.context.getApplicationContext(),
                "us-east-1:e1922be7-9b7a-421e-bf3f-ae41b0a61315", // Identity Pool ID
                Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
        );

        s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
        s3.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));

        transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, this.context.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider getCredentialProvider(){
        return credentialsProvider;
    }

    public TransferObserver startUpload(String filename, File file, CannedAccessControlList acl){
        return transferUtility.upload(MY_APP_BUCKET, filename, file, acl);
    }


}
```

Comment: `but facing issue with nougat` you can also specify the issue here!

Comment: @android_griezmann - i used ASW webservice for the backend and i can add parameter values but when i am trying to upload images/videos than its not passing image data to server in nouget. can you please help me to fix this ???

Comment: A code snippet of how you upload image? is required.

Comment: @android_griezmann - please check update thread. i added code here. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in this line (where-ever it's written)

```
Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(uri);
```

This behavior is changed in the Android Nougat. To achieve the same with Nougat
please follow  [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/3800164) as a reference. It will show you how to use **File Provider** when you set your targetSDK as 24  and change following. In your `private static Uri getImageFileUri()` method

Change this line

```
Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(uri);
```

to

```
Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", createImageFile());
```

Hope this will help you to solve your issue.

 For more go to - 
[Setting Up File Sharing - Offical documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html)